# Is there a Sum Factorial?

Tags: summation, factorial

I am curious if there is any addition factorial.

Obviously,

$$x! = \prod_{n=1}^x n$$

but what I want is a shorthand way of writing:

$$\sum_{n=1}^x n$$

So is there such a thing? and if so, what is it?

Comment: Not nearly as useful, but they are the "triangular numbers."

Comment: See [Faulhaber's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula#Examples).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\quad\mbox{or}\quad\sum_{n=1}^x n=\frac{x(x+1)}{2} $$

Answer (score 2):

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^x n$ can be shown to be equal to $\dbinom{x+1}2=\dfrac{(x+1)x}{2}$.  I doubt that there's any standard notation designed for precisely that sum.

Comment: One notation is $T_n$, and they are called triangular numbers. But no notation I know of that takes the form of a unary operator.

Comment: ok thanks! this is about what I was looking for.

Comment: There's some notational confusion between $n$ and $x$ here.

Comment: I had $n$ where $x$ should have been.  I've fixed it.